# Convert DateTime String to Integer

Tags: vb.net

I have this 2017-02-13T00:00:00+08:00 datetime as string in xml file. I want to convert it to yyyyMMdd as integer.

This is what I had tried:

```
Integer.Parse(myRow("ENT_DATE").ToString("yyyy") & myRow("ENT_DT").ToString("MM") & myRow("ENT_DT").ToString("dd"))
```

But it returns an error. `Conversion from string "yyyy" to type 'Integer' is not valid.`

`myRow("ENT_DATE")` refer to `2017-02-13T00:00:00+08:00`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `Item` property of the `DataRow` returns an `Object` reference, so you're not calling the correct `ToString` method.  That code should be:

```
CInt(CDate(myRow("ENT_DATE")).ToString("yyyyMMdd"))
```

You cast the field value as type `Date` first, then you're calling the correct `Date.ToString` method.

Comment: This gives me `20170212` and not `20170213`, probably because CDate takes the Time Zone (+8) into account and I am in a different timezone (+1). May not be a problem for OP, but still something to take into account.

Comment: @PeterB is the date will be changed according to the time zone..??

Comment: CDate will interpret the string, which has a Timezone offset (`+8`). It then produces a `DateTime` value to match the *current Timezone that the app runs in*. This will cause the Day part to be decreased by one if `hour (HH) in the source string` < (`timezone in the source string` - `timezone of your system`), and with Daylight Saving correction if needed - and I sure hope I formulated it correctly. If instead you want something simple and predictable, then see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42244568/1220550).

Answer (score 0):

Using `.ToString("yyyy")` will only work on a DateTime value, and not on a string.

The easiest way is probably just taking the digits that you need by using Left() and Replace(), and then convert those to an Integer value, like this:

```
CInt(Left(myRow("ENT_DATE"), 10).Replace("-", ""))
```

This produces `20170213` for the given input, regardless of what timezone is set for the application.

Comment: Hmmm... I was assuming that the value in the `DataTable` was actually a `DateTime`, deserialized from the XML.  If that is the case then your solution would not work but maybe I'm wrong and it actually is a `String`.  I guess that the OP must have `Option Strict Off` so, if it was a `DateTime`, then that late-bound call probably should have worked in the first place.